# Using string in Oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle

When I simply write a query in which it has code like

```
Select * from ..
where ...
AND    gfcid in ( select regexp_substr('1005771621,1001035181'||',','\d+',1,level)
        from dual
      connect by level <= (select max(length('1005771621,1001035181')-length(replace('1005771621,1001035181',',')))+1
                             from dual) )
```

It works.

But I want to make it dynamic query in oracle stored procedure. I did like this:

```
GDFCID_STRING := ' select regexp_substr('
           || '1005771621,1001035181'
           || ','
           || ','
           || '\d+'
           || ',1,level) from dual connect by level <= (select max(length('
           || '1005771621,1001035181'
           || ')-length(replace('
           || '1005771621,1001035181'
           || ','
           || ','
           || ')))+1 from dual)';

Select * from ..  
where ...
AND    gfcid in (GDFCID_STRING)
```

But it does now work.

Comment: I think a stored procedure is what you require with input variables.

Comment: why you want a dynamic query?

Comment: So you want to break the string `GDFCID_STRING` into a list of numeric values and then use it as an `in` parameter` to be compared with `gfcid`, am I right?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand your problem, you need a method to accept a comma-delimited string as an input, break it into a collection of integers and then compare a number (read: integer) with the values in this collection.

Oracle offers mainly three types of [collections](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28371/adobjcol.htm#ADOBJ00204)- [varrays](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14260/adobjcol.htm), [nested tables](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/NESTED_TABLE) and [associative arrays](http://psoug.org/reference/arrays.html). I would explain how to convert a comma-delimited string into a nested table and use it to query or compare.

First, you need to define an object type in the schema. You can write queries using this type only if you define it at schema level.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE entity_id AS OBJECT (id_val NUMBER(28));
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE entity_id_set IS TABLE OF entity_id;
/
```

Next, define a function like this:

```
FUNCTION comma_to_nt_integer (p_comma_delimited_str IN VARCHAR)
    RETURN entity_id_set IS
    v_table     entity_id_set;
BEGIN
    WITH temp AS (SELECT TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM p_comma_delimited_str) AS str FROM DUAL)
        SELECT ENTITY_ID(TRIM (REGEXP_SUBSTR (t.str,
                                    '[^,]+',
                                    1,
                                    LEVEL)))
                   str
          BULK COLLECT INTO v_table
          FROM temp t
    CONNECT BY INSTR (str,
                      ',',
                      1,
                      LEVEL - 1) > 0;

    RETURN v_table;
END comma_to_nt_integer;
```

You are done with the DDL required for this task. Now, you can simply write your query as:

```
SELECT *
  FROM ..  
 WHERE ...
       AND gfcid in (table(comma_to_nt_integer(GDFCID_STRING)));
```

Comment: Here 
in -> AND gfcid in (table(comma_to_nt_integer(GDFCID_STRING)))
in clause the sql might be different. If user is passing blank gfcId I need to put a join with another table, so in IN clause there is a dynamic query.. :( . Thank you very much for your reply.

I tried->
 AND gfcid in (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE GDFCID_STRING2) -> but it dint work as well.

Comment: @AnilGavate the query can be either fully dynamic or fully static, but not both.

Comment: I want to create a dynamic query

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar: Exactly.

Comment: @AnilGavate: Please explain your scenario further. I would suggest you post a reproducible example (as small as possible) and the precise output behavior that you expect. A set of test cases would work.

Comment: I have a variable in oracle stored proc as

GDFCID_STRING2 VARCHAR2(1000);
GDFCID_STRING := ' select regexp_substr(''1005771621,1001035181'',''[^,]+'', 1, level)         from dual
connect by regexp_substr(''1005771621,1001035181'', ''[^,]+'', 1, level) is not null ';

I want to use that variable to execute the same query in IN clause like this-> In stored proc I have one sql->

select * from xyz where gfcid in(--here I want to execute the above query (GDFCID_STRING) and feed the output of query as input to IN clause--)

Comment: Could you please add that comment as an edit to your question? This will make it better readable.

Answer (score 1):

In general you can use

`execute immediate v_your_sql_code;`

to execute dynamic SQL within PL/SQL, but from your question I'm not really aware what you want to do.

Edit:

```
y_your_sql_code := 'Select yourColumn from ..  where ...AND  gfcid in ('||GDFCID_STRING||')';

execute immediate v_your_sql_code into v_result;
```

You'll have to define `v_result` in the right datatype, you could use more then one result variable if you need more result columns, you'll need i.e. a complex type if you can retrieve more than one row.

Comment: I want to add dynamic String in the query
Like
select x from y where id in (dynamic sql)

Comment: How can I do that in IN clause?

Comment: You'll have to pass your whole Statement as string to the `execute immediate` command. And you have define variables for the result. I'll edit above.

Comment: result would be  set of Strings

Comment: Then you could select into an v_table, build i.e. as described in the answer from Rachcha.